# How to get file from form in Symfony2?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-2.3

I have form with [File Field Type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/file.html). I would like to "catch" uploaded file in controller but I don't know how to do it.

I tried to get access via `$form->get('file')`, but seems to me that this is the wrong way to go. Why? `var_dump( $form->get('file') );` return string with a filename (and nothing more)! I expected the object or something like that, but I got only a filename.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set up your form and entity right symfony will handle it automatically.

Example set up:

**Entity (Document has a file)**

```
<?php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Document;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

class Document
{
    /**
     * @var UploadedFile
     */
    protected $file;

    /**
     * @param UploadedFile $file - Uploaded File
     */
    public function setFile($file)
    {
        $this->file = $file;
    }

    /**
     * @return UploadedFile
     */
    public function getFile()
    {
        return $this->file;
    }

    //add functions described here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html
}
```

**FormType**

```
<?php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\DocumentType;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class DocumentType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('file', 'file')
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Document'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'acme_demo_document';
    }


}
```

**Controller snippet** ( probably `createAction` and `updateAction` )

```
$form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
$form->handleRequest($request);
\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($entity->getFile());
```

`$entity->getFile()` will hold the file.

Take a look here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html for instructions on how to implement moving the file from /temp to e.g. `web/uploads` and other things.

If your IDE doesn't show you what you can do with the `UploadedFile` you can look it up here: http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html

Answer (score 9):

Do this if you just want to get the file from the form:

```
$myFile = $request->files->get('inputFieldFileId');
```

this should be all you need